# How to pass an array as attribute of shortcode to work properly shortcode parser?

Tags: shortcode, escaping

`echo '[test attr="'.json_encode(array('test'=>'my[][dfd]dfds[][][')).'"]';`

//How to safe pass the array as attribute in shortcodes ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try...

- `base64_encode(serialize($array))`
- `base64_encode(json_encode($array))`

and reverse decoding in shortcode of course